# How to sort a . resx (resource file) in .NET

Tags: .net, sorting, resources, resx

I have a problem with resource files in my project. As I created one in English, I gave it to the translation team. Somehow, they returned me resource file with values in different order, so it wasn't sorted alphabetically.

So, at first it was:

```
<data name="a1" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>some text2</value>
</data>
<data name="b1" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>some text3</value>
</data>
<data name="c1" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>some text1</value>
</data>
```

and I received:

```
<data name="c1" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>some text1</value>
</data>
<data name="a1" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>some text2</value>
</data>
<data name="b1" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>some text3</value>
</data>
```

So, is there any way to sort those elements in the .resx file by the `<data name` attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SortRESX](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37022/Solving-the-resx-Merge-Problem) is a simple executable created by Tom Clement on CodeProject.

It sorts *.resx file alphabetically. I described it [on my blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20130424080759/http://tijanavujanac.posterous.com/resxdiff-solving-the-resx-merge-problem).

Comment: Can I have Visual Studio (or git) execute the SortRESX program automatically before a merge? How?

Answer (score 4):

You could write a quick script to do that using LINQ to XML:

```
var root = XElement.Load(...);
var sortedRoot = new XElement(root.Name, root.Attributes,
        root.Elements().OrderBy(e => e.Attribute("name").Value)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a [very simple VS extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7adfbbd0-de40-4caf-a591-9e1eea65bcda) that sorts resx files.
Right click any .resx file(s), and click "Sort Resx".

Comment: it seem that you are out dated, the plugin wont install on vs 2015

Comment: I fork your project, recompile it, it then installed, but no button on resource file, i also add all kind of VS to `Install Target` in `source.extension.vsixmanifest` but it also didn't bring any new context  menu too. :|

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It is quite obsolete - I recommend using [Resx Manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b64e04c-e8de-4b97-8358-06c73a97cc68) - they added sorting capabilities lately.

Comment: thank you. after installing Resx Manager, your Sort Icon also showed up.

Comment: would have used it if it only was compatible with VS 2015

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but anyways:
The great VS extension [ResXManager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ResXManager) allows you to sort the entries as well.

[image: Sort entries using ResXManager]

Additionally ResxManager has tons of other features when working with resx files.