# Visual Studio add in that alphabetizes values in a resource file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-sdk

I want to make a visual studio's add in that has the ability to sort resource files alphabetically every time someone edits a resource file. I'm not looking for a solution, but I have never used the Visual Studio sdk before. I simple want to know if anyone that has experience with the Visual Studio sdk may know if this is possible? Also any suggestions on how to start making an addin are appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a . resx (resource file) in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819793/how-to-sort-a-resx-resource-file-in-net)

Comment: You can do it without writing a plugin (just my opinion but I think it would too much work for what you're trying to do), a simple external tools program would be enough if you don't plan to sort everything automatically each time a new resource is added (resx are xml files, so it would be quite easy to sort them in an external tool)

Comment: Yeah, I have code to sort a resx file. However, in the environment that the utility would be used, it would be best if I could get it to work as an addin to visual studios.

Comment: Ok, then could you explain how you want your addin to work? Should the user click on a button to sort the file (perhaps in the ressource editor)? I have some experience with visual studio packages (which is nearly the same), so perhaps I can give you some links I found to start with (they're not that easy to find actually...)

Comment: I would like for the addin to do the sort every time someone saves a resource file, but like I said, I'm not even sure if this is possible. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have never used visual studio extensibility, I recommend you this page:
[Make a solution notebook tool window](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32906/Use-Visual-Studio-Extensibility-to-Make-a-Solution)

There is some useful information about how to interact with visual studio for saving data in sln and suo files, and also you can find information about some attributes you can use to tell visual studio what your package (or plugin) needs to do.
It's a general knowledge thing although, not directly related to what you want to do.

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525457/automating-visual-studio-with-envdte) is about how to listen to some specific events visual studio fires, it shows you general way of creating listeners in your plugin

[this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vsx/thread/e17f0688-c61b-487a-989d-222c899c554b) is actually about what you need to do (it tells you how to catch the event fired before visual studio saves a file)

and the most important one: [the source code](https://bitbucket.org/zzsergant/hgsccpackage/src/d7e76fa7fe855851a144146ab698ec804f873c8b/HgSccPackage/SccProvider.cs) for creating a custom source control for visual studio, that's where I found most of the info I needed to understand visual studio extensibility

with all these links you should get something to start with, and of course you have the [official msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165336.aspx) about extending visual studio

What you'll need to do is creating a plugin that will listen to events fired when an item is about to be saved in visual studio. I don't think there is a specific event for resx files, so you'll probably have to test which file is saved, but that should be all.
Once you have the item, you can find the physical file and sort it.

Another thing, I found out that the events declared in the DTE object don't really work (at least for me it didn't), that's why I recommend you to implement the listener pattern to catch the events you need.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I actually did [exactly that](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7adfbbd0-de40-4caf-a591-9e1eea65bcda).

You can find the source code for the extension in [GitHub](https://github.com/seldary/Ersx.Net). It shows you how the get handles for files from the Solution Explorer, add context menu actions, write to the output menu, etc..